# changing collate_fn of DataLoader in pytorch

Tags: python, pytorch, data-science, torch, pytorch-dataloader

I want to change collate_fn as below:

```
def collate_fn(batch,text_transform,SRC_LANGUAGE,TGT_LANGUAGE,PAD_IDX):
    src_batch, tgt_batch = [], []
    for src_sample, tgt_sample in batch:
        src_batch.append(text_transform[SRC_LANGUAGE](src_sample.rstrip("\n")))
        tgt_batch.append(text_transform[TGT_LANGUAGE](tgt_sample.rstrip("\n")))
```

and the error that I take is:

> TypeError: collate_fn() missing 4 required positional arguments: 'text_transform', 'SRC_LANGUAGE', 'TGT_LANGUAGE', and 'PAD_IDX'

cause the collate_fn in torch\utils\data_utils\fetch.py is defined with just taking one argument. what should I do? should I override this function?